# Overcome Gmail smtp send limit

Tags: smtp, gmail

I have a few IP cameras which sends photos to an email address if motion is detected. My problem is that someone times a lot of motion happening and the camera will flood the Gmail smtp server which results not able to send those emails. I have set the interval to 10 seconds but still missing emails. Making longer interval isn't very ideal since it's about the same effect that not capturing important photos.

Are there any good approach to overcome this limitation?

I have tried splitting into different gmail accounts but I am not getting desired results.

Comment: Try something like Mandrill, Mailgun, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the right tool for the job. Gmail is not that. Gmail is meant for normal, human users and the normal email usage pattern that goes with that.

Use a purpose-built email service like Amazon SES, Mandrill, etc., and you'll have much better results without having to resort to hackery.